# Why is Stripe not giving me a Payment Intents requires_action status when I use a 3D Secure test card number?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

In following the Stripe documentation for Billing and Subscriptions, I'm using PaymentIntents to create a subscription. It works fine if I enter a test card that doesn't require 3D Secure. But it I use one that does, instead of giving me a status of requires_action, it just gives a error on the card.

```php
//Create customer
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      "source" => $token,
      "email" => $subscriber_email)
    );

    // Get customer variables from Stripe response
    $payment_livemode = $customer->livemode;
    $payer_id = $customer->id;

    // Now put customer on subs plan    
    try {   
        $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
          "customer" => $payer_id,
          "items" => [
            [
              "plan" => $subscription_plan
            ],
          ],
           "expand" => ["latest_invoice.payment_intent"],
        ]);

        $subscription_id = $subscription->id;
        $subscription_plan_id = $subscription->items->data[0]->plan->id;
        $subscription_latest_invoice_status = $subscription->latest_invoice->status;
        $subscription_latest_invoice_id = $subscription->latest_invoice->id;
        $subscription_latest_invoice_payment_intent_status = $subscription->latest_invoice->payment_intent->status;
        $subscription_latest_invoice_payment_intent_client_secret = $subscription->latest_invoice->payment_intent->client_secret;

        $_SESSION['subscription_latest_invoice_payment_intent_client_secret'] = $subscription_latest_invoice_payment_intent_client_secret;

        if ($subscription_latest_invoice_payment_intent_status=='succeeded') {
             header("Location: ../payment-success");
        }
        if ($subscription_latest_invoice_payment_intent_status=='requires_payment_method') {
             header("Location: ../payment?payment_status=failed&inv=$subscription_latest_invoice_id");
        }
        if ($subscription_latest_invoice_payment_intent_status=='requires_action') {
             header("Location: ../payment?payment_status=requires_action");
        }
    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {

          $body = $e->getJsonBody();
          $err  = $body['error'];

          if ($err['code']=="subscription_payment_intent_requires_action") {
              header("Location: ../payment/requires_action");
          }

        } catch (\Stripe\Error\RateLimit $e) {
          // Too many requests made to the API too quickly
        } catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
          // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
        } catch (\Stripe\Error\Authentication $e) {
          // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
          // (maybe you changed API keys recently)
        } catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
          // Network communication with Stripe failed
        } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
          // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
          // yourself an email
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
        }
```

I'm using test cards on this page:
https://stripe.com/docs/testing#three-ds-cards

I have chosen the card with this number:
4000 0000 0000 3220

Here's my error details:
Status:402
Type:card_error
Code:subscription_payment_intent_requires_action
Message:Payment for this subscription requires additional user action before it can be completed successfully. Please refer to the use of the `enable_incomplete_payments` parameter here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/lifecycle#incomplete-opt-in

My API version is 2018-05-21.

Can anyone give me a clue to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Andy! Could you tell us more about what error you're getting? What is the message? 
Also, what API version are you on? Since you're using Subscriptions with 3DS, in case you haven't seen this doc, it might be helpful: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/strong-customer-authentication#upgrading-integration

Comment: What card are you using and can you provide a dump of the response?

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I've edited my question with more info. I'm not upgrading an existing system, but creating a new one, so I've been following the documentation on this page:https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment

Comment: Hi Andy, since you are on an older API version, to support 3DS on subscriptions, you should be using this guide instead: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/strong-customer-authentication#upgrading-integration
This means updating your API version or passing the `enable_incomplete_payments` flag when creating the subscription, as the error message points out.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my API to the latest version and added enable_incomplete_payments and now it works fine! Thanks. However, when using one of the cards that's meant to fail, it keeps coming up with uncaught exceptions when the card errors. I am using the same code as in this page to catch errors: https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling

Comment: The card I'm using is: 4000 0000 0000 9995

Answer (score 5):

Answered in the comments, just posting here for visibility:

Hi Andy, since you are on an older API version, to support 3DS on subscriptions, you should be using this guide instead: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/strong-customer-authentication#upgrading-integration.

This means updating your API version or passing the enable_incomplete_payments flag when creating the subscription, as the error message points out.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and actually, the API version is not the version of the library you download, you have to change it in your dashboard, https://dashboard.stripe.com/developers